Silencing internal samples on digital piano when using external sound engine
I have purchased a Yamaha YDP-165 for the kids to learn. I like the keys, and the sounds are good enough for the kids, but I don’t find the samples overly exciting. I would like to use some external sound engine, like that of Pianoteq instead when I practice myself.
When I connect a device to the piano’s “USB to host”, I get both midi input and also USB audio output. Up to here, it is all good. Music software (Pianoteq, GarageBand, etc.), detect the input and play their samples through the piano’s speakers.
The problem is, I can’t find a way to silent the piano’s internal samples. As a result, the sounds from the music software get overlayed on the internal sounds from the piano itself, creating a murky and muddled output.
Is there a way to have the piano output only what it receives from the external sound engine, completely bypassing its internal sounds?

Uh, onboard volume knob?

@AndyBonner but if I understood correctly the op outputs the external sound via the piano loudspeakers, both will probably be affected by the volume knob?

Yes both are affected by the master volume.

The ability to disable the internal sounds is usually called something like ‘local control’ or ‘local off’.
As they say: when all else fails, read the manual…  The YDP-165 downloads page on the Yamaha web site provides all the relevant manuals.  Page 2 of the MIDI Reference manual has a section called ‘Local Control ON/OFF’:

“Local Control” refers to the fact that, normally, the keyboard of the instrument controls its internal tone generator,
allowing the internal voices to be played directly from the keyboard. This situation is “Local Control On,” since the internal
tone generator is controlled locally by its own keyboard. Local Control can be turned off as desired, so that the keyboard
of the instrument does not play the internal voices.
While holding down [DEMO/SONG] and [PIANO/VOICE], press the B3 key. Pressing the B3 key repeatedly toggles between Local Control On and Off.
Default setting: ON

(The main Owner's Manual doesn't describe this, but its penultimate page has diagrams showing the various functions assigned to each key, and it includes Local Control.)
Since that sounds exactly what you want, I suggest you try holding [DEMO/SONG] + [PIANO/VOICE] and then tapping the B3 key!

I did not know the terminology (Local Control). Thanks for the reference.
